# Pandas filtering with tuples and wildcard

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way of using the pandas `isin` method with tuples and wildcard?

In the example below, is there a way of making `out` to be `[True, False, True]` by rewriting the code and using the wildcard search with the tuple `[1,None]`?

```
df     = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3], 'Age':[60,3,5]})
dfDict = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,3],   'Age':[None,5]})
display(df, dfDict)

tup  = [tuple(x) for x in dfDict.values]
out = df.apply(tuple, 1).isin(tup).values.tolist()
print(out)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your example it is possble to just check on `ID` like following:

```
lst  = dfDict.ID.values.tolist()
out = df.ID.isin(lst).values.tolist()

print(out)
[True, False, True]
```

Another way to check if values of your `df` are present in `dfDict` is using the `merge` method from pandas and ask for `indicator` while doing the join like following:

```
merged = pd.merge(df, dfDict[['ID']], on=['ID'], how='left', indicator=True)

print(merged)
   ID  Age     _merge
0   1   60       both
1   2    3  left_only
2   3    5       both
```

Does this answer your question?